# Closed db connection while trying to sign in after registration using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing a Rails 3.2.12 app using Devise as my authentication system. Everything works fine except when I try to automatically sign in the new user after he is registers in the app.

This is what I'm doing to achieve this in my controller:

```
...
resource.save!

if resource.active_for_authentication?
  set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
else
  ...
end
```

When it tries to execute the sign_in, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RegistrationsController#create
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `sessions`.`id` = 684
```

It seems as it's trying to delete the current session and that is the reason for that error...

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank yo very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After the user registers, they'll automatically be signed in with stock devise. In fact, you shouldn't need to write any controller code whatsoever for a default devise setup.

That said, if for some reason you really need a custom controller, you could try forcing a signout first:

```
sign_out(resource_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Felix, but I'm afraid it's still giving me that error.